# Practical way to only return selected columns in Laravel in method

Tags: laravel

I am doubting (life of a junior developer) what would be the most practical way to only return the value from a specific column in Laravel of a database record.

Example controller method:

```
public function show(ProductsCategory $category)
{ 
   return $category;
}
```

This outputs all the columns, like this

```
{"id":104,"category_name":"Soft drinks","created_at":"2021-06-09T17:16:54.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-06-09T17:16:54.000000Z"}
```

However what I am after is just getting the `category_name` column retuned, like this

```
{"category_name":"Soft drinks"}
```

I can accomplish this by doing

```
    public function show($id)
    { 
       $category = ProductsCategory::select('category_name')->findOrFail($id);

       echo json_encode($category)
       exit;
    }
```

However doubting if this would be the most practical way to go? Is there an more elegant/straight forward way? Or am I grossly overthinking this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get full control over returned resource you should use [API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources).

To create resource file run:
`php artisan make:resource ProductsCategoryResource`

In resource file you can define fields to return, i.e. if you need only `id` and `name` you do this:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class ProductCategoryResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
        ];
    }
}
```

Then, set response in controller:

```php
public function show($id)
{ 
  $category = ProductsCategory::select('id', 'name')->findOrFail($id);
  return new ProductCategoryResource($category);
}
```

You can also return resource collection:

```php
public function index()
{ 
  $categories = ProductsCategory::select('id', 'name')->get()l
  return ProductCategoryResource::collection($category);
}
```

I think this is really elegant and organized way.

Answer (score 2):

I think its developer choice . One way to select column like you mentioned .Another way  is like below

```
 $category = ProductsCategory::findOrFail($id,['category_name']);
```

By default `findOrFail($id, $columns = ['*'])` return all columns so they mentioned *

Also instead of `json_encode` as json,you can directly return `$category`

Also if you want to pass custom headers or status code then you can return like below

```
 return response()->json($category)
```

Here is json method params

```
 /**
     * Create a new JSON response instance.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $data
     * @param  int  $status
     * @param  array  $headers
     * @param  int  $options
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function json($data = [], $status = 200, array $headers = [], $options = 0);
```